# GDownloadUrl is not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-maps-api-2

This is inside a [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) site. I sent an Ajax request using `GDownloadUrl` using the following code. I got this `GDownloadurl` method from the Google Maps JavaScript API version 2:

```
GDownloadUrl(down_load_url, function(data) {
    var xml = GXml.parse(data);
});
```

This `down_load_url` has the request and the data variable will get the response as an XML.

However, in Chrome this data variable contains nothing. In other browsers this function gets the requested data correctly. What is the wrong with Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gentleman has an example of using GDownloadUrl at: http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/02/gdownloadurl-update-better-error.html

You might try adding the responseCode parameter to your callback function to see if Chrome is erroring for some reason. This example works in my version of Chrome, so make sure you are running the latest version.

Here is his code example:

```
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

    // Download the data in data.xml and load it on the map. The format we
    // expect is:
    // <markers>
    //   <marker lat="37.441" lng="-122.141"/>
    //   <marker lat="37.322" lng="-121.213"/>
    // </markers>
    GDownloadUrl("data.xml", function(data, responseCode) {
      // To ensure against HTTP errors that result in null or bad data,
      // always check status code is equal to 200 before processing the data
      if(responseCode == 200) {
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
    }
      } else if(responseCode == -1) {
    alert("Data request timed out. Please try later.");
      } else { 
        alert("Request resulted in error. Check XML file is retrievable.");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: :thanks for the reply.using your code I fall into else condition.that is i got an alert telling "Request resulted in error. Check XML file is retrievable".still I didn't get what error happen here.please can you help me.thanks

Comment: hey thanks again.problem was sloved.using your code I detected the response code.it was 0.one of the reasons for getting zero for response code is "on firewalls".after closing my windows and kaspersky firewalls I got the required result.thanks