# Parsing XML to a google map to create multiple markers

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-maps, xml-parsing

Todays issue is this:

```
    GDownloadUrl("http://www.mysite/map.php", 
    
    function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
      //var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
     
      //for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        //var address = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("location")));
        
        //var latlong = address.split(",");            
        
        //var latlongtomap = new GLatLng(parseFloat(latlong[0]), parseFloat(latlong[1]));
       
        var latlongtomap = new GLatLng(51.477711,-3.176555);

        var marker = createMarker(latlongtomap);
        
        map.addOverlay(marker);
     // }
    });
  }
}
```

If I run this it will get the Lat and Long coords and create a marker on a map for me. However, if I attempt to get the "location"tab from my php script (using all the commented out code):

map.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT MAPADDRESS FROM report";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
$node = $doc->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $doc->appendChild($node);
header("Content-type: text/xml");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $node = $doc->createElement("marker");
   $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
   $newnode->setAttribute("location", $row['MAPADDRESS']);
}
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

results of this are:

```
<markers>
   <marker location="51.477711,-3.176555"/>
   <marker location="51.472512,-3.187527"/>
   <marker location="51.471057,-3.186263"/>
   <marker location="51.473261,-3.192219"/>
</markers>
```

Why will the code not read this PHP properly?

Comment: Just a note, you're using version 2 of the Maps API, but that's deprecated, and could be shut off as early as next year.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
var latlong = markers[i].getAttribute("location").split(",");            
var latlongtomap = new GLatLng(parseFloat(latlong[0]), parseFloat(latlong[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see what you mean, but the lat and long are saved a DB as one entity. that's why I used the split string operation to separate them out. I've double checked that with a hard coded coordinate. This issue here is with parsing the XML data from my php in the first place. It just doesn't seem to want to read anything from the php :(

Comment: Take a look again, I revised my answer :), I realized after I posted that you just have an unnecessary step in there.

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks Javram. I see my inefficiencies lol. I'm still stuck with the issue of this code not getting the php file though. Highly frustrating :@

Comment: Keep in mind that the file needs to be available on the public internet in order to use GDownloadUrl.  If you are pointing to a file on your local machine, the GDownloadUrl will not work.

Comment: Just tried the page you posted, and it looks like it is working for me.  What browser are you testing it in (Works in Firefox)?

Comment: HAHAHAHA oh how I hate Chrome right now. Been at this for HOURS!!!! thanks four your help dude!

Comment: New problem though. It seems that GDownloadUrl only works in Firefox and not IE or Chrome. This is a very big inconvenience :(

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147079/gdownloadurl-is-not-working-on-chrome

Comment: Ahh kool, now chrome is telling me that I have an error with reading the xml it should be getting. Yet it still works on Firefox :S

Comment: Instead of using GDownloadURL,  you could always get and parse the XML with jquery,  kind of like here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Comment: Hey, thanks for that link that came in handy for something else I did. I also found the problem for the GDownloadURL to be that i forgot the www. ...... the WWW. ...... -_- lol.